# Joomla GET/POST variable as string and whitespace

Tags: variables, joomla, get

How do I retrieve joomla posted variable to not be trimmed on white space.

```
posted variable (string) 'Test Variable'

$jinput->get('MyVariable');
```

returns

```
'TestVariable'
```

but I need

```
'Test Variable'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between I found the answer `$jinput->getString();`